# The rank of an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that there's a relation between the rank of matrix and whether it is invertible or not.
What should the rank of the matrix equal to in order for the matrix to be invertible ?
The other small question is what's an Nonsingular matrix ?

Comment: Explain better please rank(A) = its dimension ?

Comment: the second part question which is what's a nonsingular matrix ?

Comment: Explain better please what "the matrix" means. I suppose $A\in M_n(K)$ for a field $K$? $A$ is called nonsingular if it has full rank (or if it is invertible). Please have a look into a text on linear algebra, it is explained there.

Comment: Yes for example yes

Comment: thanks : nonsingluar means that the matrix has its determinant non zero which implies that the matrix is invertible which then implies that it's full-ranked. that's the explanation i wanted to have first. Now thanks anyways !